# list in loop, Nonetype errors

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my Code

```
def printList(stringlist):
    empty = []
    if stringlist is None:
        print empty
    else:
        print stringlist

def add (stringlist, string):
    string = [] if string is None else string
    if stringlist is not None:
        stringlist.insert(0, string)
    else:
        stringlist.append(1)
```

it somehow appears "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

I was originally looking for the code to be run like this:

```
>>> myList = None
>>> printList(myList)
[]
>>> for word in ['laundry','homework','cooking','cleaning']:
myList = add(myList, word)
printList(myList)
[laundry]
[homework, laundry]
[cooking, homework, laundry]
[cleaning, cooking, homework, laundry]
```

Comment: Just to watch out for, in your desired output you assign the return value of 'add' to myList, however add doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have already pointed out, the problem is that in your `else` case the list is `None`. But this is only part of the problem. Instead of appending to `None`, you'd have to create a new list in the `else` case, but then you'd also have to `return` the list, as you are no longer editing `stringlist` in-place.

You should (and seem to expect to) return the list anyway, since otherwise `mylist` will be `None` after you do `myList = add(myList, word)` in your loop.

Also, your line `string = [] if string is None else string` is somewhat odd, as this will insert an empty list into the list in case the string is `None`.

I suggest you change your `add` method to something like this:

```
def add (stringlist, string):
    item = [] if string is None else [string]
    return item + (stringlist or [])
```

This will wrap the string in a list (or create an empty list if the string is `None`) and return a new list constructed from that string and the old list (or another empty list if that list is `None`). (`a or b` is equivalent to `a if a else b`). Similarly, your `printList` can be simplified to something like:

```
def printList(stringlist):
    print stringlist or []
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `append` method from `None` object:

```
if stringlist is not None:
    stringlist.insert(0, string)
else:
    # stringlist is None
    # Well, let's append to it!
    stringlist.append(1)
```

Comment: like it is a must to make myList = None
then what can i do in the 'add', in order to let the code run on stringlist.insert(0, string)?

Answer (score 1):

```
if stringlist is not None:
    stringlist.insert(0, string)
else:
    stringlist.append(1)
```

When `stringlist` is not `None`, you insert something, but when it is `None` (else clause), you are appending something to it. You cannot append something to `stringlist` because it's None.

Comment: like it is a must to make myList = None
then what can i do in the 'add', in order to let the code run on stringlist.insert(0, string)?